# Build with an existing `.bbl` file

Tags: bibtex

I have downloaded the latex source of a monograph from arxiv. This includes the `.bbl` file they had to submit. However, if I make any changes myself and recompile, I generate a new **empty** `.bbl` file, since there is no `.bib` file included in the submission, causing me to lose all references.

How can I edit/build a latex a document and reuse an already creted `.bbl` file?

Comment: Try replacing the line `\bibliography{file.bib}` by the contents of the .bbl file.

Comment: Answer tested with bibtex. Compile once without the bbl file there (No bibliography file at all). then copy the `bbl` file in the folder of your main file and compile again twice. (All compilations with pdflatex... none with `bibtex`)

Answer (score 4):

`bbl` file is just a `tex` file containing latex code of the bibliography after creating this code via the usage of `bibtex` or `biber` etc according to our chosen style.

For example a minimal main file with bibtex usage could be:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\cite{testcite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

The bibliography file is:

sample.bib:

```
@article{testcite,
author={Just Me},
title={No needed},
year={2018}}
```

Then we compile the file once with:

```
pdflatex main
```

Then once with:

```
bibtex main
```

This step creates a latex code file like shown below (`bbl` file):

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{testcite}
Just Me.
\newblock No needed.
\newblock 2018.

\end{thebibliography}
```

and finally twice with:

```
pdflatex main
```

Steps like no `bib` file exist:

1) Now... lets move all the files except `main.tex` at a folder (to hide them foom pdflatex)... and run `pdflatex main`.

A pdf will be created with a [?] instead of citation.

2) Copy just `main.bbl` in the `main.tex`'s folder and rerun `pdflatex main` twice.

Output:

[image]