# What does the BBL file-extension stand for in LaTeX?

Tags: bibtex, xetex, external-files

The file format extension of `.bib` stands for the "**bib**liography"; a file that the BibTeX engine gets as an input. The file-format-extension of `.bst`  has been derived from the expression of "**b**ibliography **st**yle", as an equivalent command in LaTeX represents the same.
But, what does the `.bbl` file-extension stand for in LaTeX? Is it derived from, or has something to do with the "**b**i**b**liography **l**ibrary" or perhaps "**b**i**b**liography for **L**aTeX", or even "**b**i**b**liography **l**ists"?!

I appreciate response, specially the ones with references.

Comment: `bbl`  is a `tex` file after the `bib` compilation through bibtex or biblatex/biber etc [according to the bibliography style file (`bst`)]. Take a look to this related on how to use in order to understand more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417440/120578

Comment: @koleygr I know where is this file comes from and what is that for, but I don't sure about that `bbl` file extension stands for what words in abbreviation?

Comment: Possibly/Probably "BiBLiography". In Greek it is easy to suppose that because BIBLIO is the BOOK and BIBLIOGRAPHY comes from BIBLIO and GRAPHO=WRITE.

Comment: Well, it _could_ also mean “Better Be LaTeX [code this time around]!”. Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @KessVargavind No it couldn't, because there should be a relative LaTeX concepts around for these extensions.

Answer (score 8):

It is just a part of a filename it doesn't have to stand for anything, and I have never seen it defined as an acronym.

However this is introduced in the LaTeX Book by the phrase

> When BiBTeX is run, it reads information from the auxiliary file and produces a file named `myfile.bbl` containing the LaTeX commands to produce the source list.

The "source list" phrase is used two or three times more in the BibTeX description in that section so you might say it stands for "**B**i**B**liography **L**ist" or "**B**i**BL**iography".

But mostly it is just a three letter file extension with a name different from `.bib` (the bibtex input) and `.blg` (the bibtex log).

Comment: I think this is very natural to say that `.bbl` extension stands for **b**i**b**liography **l**ist(s). Is that true?

Comment: @Qaher there is no true or not true, it is just a three letter extension as part of a filename it does not really stand for anything, although as I show in this answer the words "Bibliography" and "List" were probably in Leslie Lamport's mind at the time.

Comment: That's exactly where the ambiguity arises! The founder of such files is a "LaTeX"ist, and this type of files gets created only in LaTeX, not in the very TeX. That's why such a doubt comes into mind, that should it have anything to do with the expression of "**b**i**b**liography **l**atex", or does it!

Comment: @Qaher as I have said repeatedly now, it is just a file extension it does not have to have any connection with any English words. Perhaps Leslie Lamport had some words in mind when thinking of the extension, perhaps not but as far as I can see it is not documented as meaning anything anywhere.

Comment: I've already got your idea, It's not documented and does not necessarily need to convey any semantics; However, it's doesn't seem to be just some random characters; I just wanted to dig into, and reveal the possible idea behind of it!

Comment: @Qaher it is not defined as an acronym in the LaTeX Book, or in the comments in the latex sources or in the source code of bibtex.